# Не адаптируется slick slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Не могу адаптировать slick slider**. Перепробовал все способы, которые только нашёл, но ничего не получается. Код

```
                <section class="film">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="film__inner">
                            <p class="vertical-text film__text">
                                Лучшие
                            </p>
                            <div class="film__variants">
                                <div class="film__item">
                                    <div class="film__item-inner">
                                        <div class="film__general">
                                            <div class="film__general--img">
                                                <img src="images/spnwhposter.jpg" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="film__general--gen">
                                                <h3 class="film__general-title">
                                                    Человек-паук: Нет пути домой
                                                </h3>
                                                <div class="film__general--inf">
                                                    <ul class="film__general-list">
                                                        <li class="film__general-item">
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-left">
                                                                Год
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-right">
                                                                2021
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="film__general-item">
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-left">
                                                                Страна
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-right">
                                                                США, Индия
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="film__general-item">
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-left">
                                                                Режиссёр
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-right">
                                                                Джон Уоттс
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="film__general-item">
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-left">
                                                                Жанр
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-right">
                                                                фантастика, боевик, приключения, фэнтези
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="film__general-item">
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-left">
                                                                Бюджет
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-right">
                                                                $200 000 000
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="film__general-item">
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-left">
                                                                Продолжительность
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-right">
                                                                148 мин. / 02:28
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="film__media">
                                            <video src="video/Человек-Паук_ нет пути домой - официальный трейлер.mp4" controls="controls" poster="images/teaser.jpg" muted="muted"></video>
                                            <div class="film__media-text">
                                                <h4 class="film__media-title">
                                                    Человек-паук: Нет пути домой
                                                </h4>
                                                <p class="film__media-actors">
                                                    Актёры: Том Холланд, Зендея, Бенедикт Камбербэтч, Мариса Томей, Уиллем Дефо, Альфред Молина, Джейми Фокс
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="film__descr">
                                            Жизнь и репутация Питера Паркера оказываются под угрозой, поскольку Мистерио раскрыл всему миру тайну личности Человека-паука. Пытаясь исправить ситуацию, Питер обращается за помощью к Стивену Стрэнджу, но вскоре всё становится намного опаснее.
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="film__images">
                                            <a href="images/smnwhimg1.jpg"><img src="images/smnwhimg1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                            <a href="images/smnwhimg2.jpg"><img src="images/smnwhimg2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                            <a href="images/smnwhimg3.jpg"><img src="images/smnwhimg3.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                            <a href="images/smnwhimg4.jpg"><img src="images/smnwhimg4.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                            <a href="images/smnwhimg5.jpg"><img src="images/smnwhimg5.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                            <a href="images/smnwhimg6.jpg"><img src="images/smnwhimg6.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="film__item">
                                    <div class="film__item-inner">
                                        <div class="film__general">
                                            <div class="film__general--img">
                                                <img src="images/spnwhposter.jpg" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="film__general--gen">
                                                <h3 class="film__general-title">
                                                    Человек-паук: Нет пути домой
                                                </h3>
                                                <div class="film__general--inf">
                                                    <ul class="film__general-list">
                                                        <li class="film__general-item">
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-left">
                                                                год
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-right">
                                                                2021
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="film__general-item">
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-left">
                                                                страна
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-right">
                                                                США, Индия
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="film__general-item">
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-left">
                                                                Режиссёр
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-right">
                                                                Джон Уоттс
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="film__general-item">
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-left">
                                                                Жанр
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-right">
                                                                фантастика, боевик, приключения, фэнтези
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="film__general-item">
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-left">
                                                                Бюджет
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-right">
                                                                $200 000 000
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                        <li class="film__general-item">
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-left">
                                                                Продолжительность
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="film__general-item-right">
                                                                148 мин. / 02:28
                                                            </div>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="film__media">
                                            <video src="video/Человек-Паук_ нет пути домой - официальный трейлер.mp4" controls="controls" poster="images/teaser.jpg" muted="muted"></video>
                                            <div class="film__media-text">
                                                <h4 class="film__media-title">
                                                    Человек-паук: Нет пути домой
                                                </h4>
                                                <p class="film__media-actors">
                                                    Актёры: Том Холланд, Зендея, Бенедикт Камбербэтч, Мариса Томей, Уиллем Дефо, Альфред Молина, Джейми Фокс
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="film__descr">
                                            Жизнь и репутация Питера Паркера оказываются под угрозой, поскольку Мистерио раскрыл всему миру тайну личности Человека-паука. Пытаясь исправить ситуацию, Питер обращается за помощью к Стивену Стрэнджу, но вскоре всё становится намного опаснее.
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="film__images">
                                            <a href="images/smnwhimg1.jpg"><img src="images/smnwhimg1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                            <a href="images/smnwhimg2.jpg"><img src="images/smnwhimg2.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                            <a href="images/smnwhimg3.jpg"><img src="images/smnwhimg3.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                            <a href="images/smnwhimg4.jpg"><img src="images/smnwhimg4.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                            <a href="images/smnwhimg5.jpg"><img src="images/smnwhimg5.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                            <a href="images/smnwhimg6.jpg"><img src="images/smnwhimg6.jpg" alt=""></a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</section>
```

```
.film__inner {
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 1fr / 35px 100%;
}
.film__variants {
    background-color: #07131B;
    color: #fff;
    max-width: 100%;
}
.film__item {
    margin: 12px 0 0 12px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```
$('.film__variants').slick({
    prevArrow: '<button class="slick-prev slick-arrow"><img src="images/icon/left-arrow.png" width="32px" alt=""></button>',
    nextArrow: '<button class="slick-next slick-arrow"><img src="images/icon/right-arrow.png" width="32px" alt=""></button>',
    dots: true,
});
```

Comment: Если конкретнее, то при изменении ширины, слайдер не адаптируется. А когда убираю его - всё адаптируется

Answer (score 0):

Решено (возможно это костыль, но хоть как-то). Короче! На .slick-list. draggable (это классы, которые даёт js, когда мы задаём слайдер) поставил свойства max-width: 92vw. Далее .film__item .slick-slide .slick-current .slick-active (Там тоже все классы, кроме первого заданы самим JS и я переопределяю их значения) задал свойства max-width: 100vw. В моём случае это помогло.